# Pushing all the numbers on a line in a file into a stringstream

Tags: c++, string, stl, fstream, stringstream

For my map creation algorithm, the user inputs numbers such as this in a data file:

```
0, 3, 0, 0
14, 2, 26, 5
```

The numbers represent the id of a certain texture of a tile in order to generate cell/world data. I've already made the part that takes away the commas to make it look like this:

```
0 3 0 0
14 2 26 5
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to push the certain numbers into a stringstream so they can be parsed and given the correct texture. The certain numbers will be 1 space away from each other so it's easy to push it into the stringstream, but how would I jump from each number to another in order to push it into the stringstream in the same order?

Thanks!

Comment: The title says push all numbers into a stringstream but then you later say you want to push *certain* numbers into the stringstream. Which one is it and what kind of numbers are you trying to use?

Comment: I think this could be done more efficiently if you told us what the data _is_, so we can skip several middlemen.

Comment: I can't be the only one that has no idea what you just asked. You say you removed the commas, but no explanation for *why*. Crafting an algorithm for reading lines of text, skipping commas as delimiters and parsing out int values as required per line should be doable without having to prestrip commas first.

Comment: Ok. Let me be more clear. What I want to do is get all of the individual numbers separated by commas and save them as ints. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
std::string snumbers = ...; // your input string with no commas
std::stringstream sstream(snumbers);

std::vector<std::string> items;
std::string item;
while(sstream >> item) items.push_back(item);

const size_t N = items.size() / 2; // this is the number of pairs you have

std::cout << "pair 0: " << items[0] << ", " << items[N] << std::endl;
std::cout << "pair 1: " << items[1] << ", " << items[1+N] << std::endl;
...
```